# How to redirect from old domain to a new subdomain by .htaccess file in openshift rhc

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, openshift

I have two sites in openshift rhc. For the first one I use **cloudflare** and tk domain by name of www.elasa.ir and set my first site by the name of ***first.rhcloud.com*** .

I want to have a sub domain for the first domain similar to dl1.example.com that redirects to the second site in openshift rhc.

I added the ***dl1.example.com*** in the secondry site in openshift rhc as a CNAME, and set it to ***secondery-.rhcloud.com*** to ***shope.elasa.ir***
and in **cloudeflare** in setting of ***example.com***.

I added a CNAME record for pointing  **[shope.elasa.ir](http://shope.elasa.ir)** to ***secondery-.rhcloud.com***
and finally by clicking to dl1.example.com it showing the secondary site, but after another clicking the address-bar change to secondery-.rhcloud.com.
So what i must to do for redirecting the secondery-.rhcloud.com to subdomain (dl1.exmple.com) for all the time:

I added an .htaccess file with this code:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?tomatocart-beyhagh.rhcloud\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/shope\.elasa\.ir\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but I get the following error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a alias domain in OpenShift console and redirect to your subdomain.

Use cloudflare to create your subdomain and setting a CNAME to `secondery-.rhcloud.com`.